# Copy values in a column based on last row in another column

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have an Excel sheet with a four-column setup.

[image: Excel Screen dump]

I'm trying to copy the content of the cells in column B to column C as long as there are active rows in any cells of these 4 columns. By that, I mean including the value a11.

This is supposed to work in an Excel template by an autorun macro to fill out a form. I have tried many ways I found on different sites but nothing works. They all seem to stop at the first blank cell in any row.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    With Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        Sheets("Upload").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Resize(.Count) = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The output of my last code (posted here) ends at first empty cell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba). See this question for a robust way to find the last cell in a column.

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work:

This function finds the last used row in the Entire Sheet.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Sheets("Upload").Range("C1:C" & LastRow(ActiveSheet)).Value = Sheets("Upload").Range("B1:B" & LastRow(ActiveSheet)).Value

End Sub


Function LastRow(Sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=Sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```